Azure function app not logging information messages to app insights traces log
Please bear with me as this is my first question.
I have a function app (V4 runtime) with an EventHub trigger created in VS 2022 in C# and deployed to Azure.  I have configured app insights so I can log to there from the code.
I am seeing the warning and error messages getting logged to the traces table but not information or trace messages, using a KQL query like this:
traces
| where timestamp > ago(60min) 
| order by timestamp desc


Here is a block of debug code I have in the function app:
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"(LOG) Received event count = {events.Length}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"(INFO) Received event count = {events.Length}");
            _logger.LogWarning($"(WARN) Received event count = {events.Length}");
            _logger.LogError($"(ERR) Received event count = {events.Length}");
            _logger.LogTrace($"(TRACE) Received event count = {events.Length}");


I am getting only the (WARN) and (ERROR) logs.
I've tried numerous settings in the host.json and I cant get this to show the information messages.
Per this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories
Under the "loglevel" in host.json, I've tried "Function.myfunc.User":"Information" I've tried "Function":"Information", "Function.myfunc":"Information" all to no avail. (I am using myfunc here but in the host.json I have the name of the function).   I am assuming I am supposed to use the name of the Function() attribute and not the actual name of the function "app".   And yes I have checked that it matches the case exactly of the function name.
I've tried with and without a "default":"Information", still not working.
Per this:  Azure Function Application Insights Logging not Honoring Host.json Configuration
It says to remove the default filters, but I have no default filter listed there.
Clearly the app insights connection is working since I am getting some messages.
Note that if I run this in the debugger I get all messages to the console screen as expected.
Also this is a very low volume application (5000 items a day spread out) so performance is not really an issue here.
If there's an easier way to do some simple logging I am open for suggestions.
UPDATED Here is my complete host.json, and I am still getting only warnings and errors:

{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}


Thank you.

For application insights set the log level under Logging/ApplicationInsights/LogLevel. This is in addition to Logging/LogLevel
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}

Also, update the default behavior of applicationInsights by removing the default filter rule (see Managing log levels)
var applicationInsightsProviderName = "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider";

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            var defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == applicationInsightsProviderName);

            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();


Thanks, I have incorporated your suggestion and I have updated the original question with my host.json file.    I am still getting only errors and warnings however.  If I use "Logging" with a capital L as indicated in your example, the editor gives me a schema warning on line 1 with a green underline.    I also get the warning and green underline on line 1 if I use "applicationInsights" with a lowercase a, which is exactly what the type-ahead provides, so I am not sure which way is correct.   Is your example above actually part of a working function app?

Did you add the same to appsettings.json too?

I dont have an appsettings.json - am I supposed to have one?  This is running as an isolated process by the way.

How does the HostBuilder() looks like? It would be in the Program.cs. Add that to the question so we know how the app is configured.

Please verify that .ConfigureLogging  looks similar to code (and link) posted above.
